# Eigenvalues of symmetric part of product of matrices

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, hurwitz-matrices

Consider a real matrix $B$ defined as

$$ B := X A + A^T X $$

where $X$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $A$ has eigenvalues with positive real parts. How can I prove that eigenvalues of $B$ also have positive real parts?

Note that since $B$ is symmetric, its eigenvalues are real.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is not true. As a counter example, select

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} ~~\text{and}~~ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrices

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ -1 & 3\end{bmatrix}\ \mathrm{and}\ X=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

The matrix $A$ has two real positive eigenvalues. However, we have that $$A^TX+XA=\begin{bmatrix}    20 &  -11\\   -11   &  6\end{bmatrix},$$

which has a negative eigenvalues. So, the implication you want to prove it not true.

What can be done is the other way round, though. Assume that $A$ and $B$ are given. If $X$ satisfies this equation, then we have that

$$X=\int_0^\infty e^{-A^Ts}Be^{-As}ds$$

where the integral is well-defined since $A$ has eigenvalues with positive real part.

Indeed, we have that
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
A^TX+XA&=&\displaystyle A^T\int_0^\infty e^{-A^Ts}Be^{-As}ds+\int_0^\infty e^{-A^Ts}Be^{-As}dsA\\
&=&\displaystyle \int_0^\infty -\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(e^{-A^Ts}Be^{-As}\right)ds\\
&=&B.
\end{array}$$

Therefore, if $B$ is positive definite, then $X$ is positive definite as well. Moreover, if $B=C^TC$ for some matrix $C$ such that the pair $(A,C)$ is observable, then $X$ will also be positive definite.

---

**Edit.** Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $C\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$. The pair $(A,C)$ is observable if the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}C\\CA\\\vdots\\CA^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$$ is full-rank.

Comment: "The pair (A,C) is observable" That is, $AC = CA$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I have updated the answer.